# How to get individual words to go over multiple lines in the cells of table

Tags: longtable, wrap

I know how to get sentences of words to wrap in a cell, namely using `|p{cell width}|`, but what if I want a word itself to split over multiple lines? I would like your response to work for longtable in particular. For instance:

```tex
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.6cm}|}
Mixture \\\hline
\end{longtable}
```

should provide an example of the behaviour I don't want. Where mixture doesn't wrap across lines and instead the cell border goes through the word. Is there a way to get the word to split into say mixt on the first line and ure on the next line with a - after the first line to indicate it continues onto the next line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
% \usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
% \showhyphens{Mixture}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.6cm}|}
  \hline % (added for nicer looks)
  % core TeX syntax:
  % \nobreak\hskip0pt\relax
  % or with overhead:
  \hspace*{0pt}%
  Mixture \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Notice that with engine LuaLaTeX the hyphenation of first word in a paragraph is not inhibited so you don't need the `\hspace*` trick.

[image: single word being split]

---

With `array` package syntax you can automatize this

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
% \usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
% \showhyphens{Mixture}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\hspace*{0pt}}p{0.6cm}|}
  \hline
  Mixture \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```